# Having trouble getting element to expand to height = 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm using Win XP and have noticed this on Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  I have three block elements, aligned vertically.  I want the container to have a minimum height of 600 pixels, and I would like the middle element to take up as much vertical space as possible.  Problem is, even if I specify height:100% for the middle element, it doesn't expand to fill the space.  Here is the HTML ...

```
        <div class="productDetailsPanel">
            <div class="tabPanel">
                <div class="tabBar">Tab Bar</div>
                <div class="tabContent">Content</div>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button value="Save">Save</button></td>
                        <td><button value="Reset">Reset</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the CSS ...

```
.productDetailsPanel {
    width: 74%;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: #BBBBBB;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.tabPanel { 
    height:100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    background-color:pink; 
    padding: 2px;    
}

.tabBar { 
    height: 2em;    
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
}

.tabContent { 
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I also created this JSFiddle to illustrate this madness -- http://jsfiddle.net/XAYWZ/ .  Anyone know how I can adjust my CSS so that the middle panel takes up as much vertical space as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Change the bar with the buttons in it to

```
position: absolute;
```

and give it the attribute

```
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: Did you try that with the existing code?  That isn't working for me on either JS fiddle or my own machine.

Comment: That's odd, it was working when I tried in on there. I'll take a look.